# "Subir" vs. "Subir en"

Tags: gramática

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia de significado entre "subir" y "subir en". Por ejemplo: "Las tasas de interés subieron/subieron en una mitad de centésimo ayer". ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero incorrecto usar "en" con el verbo "subir" (cuando significa "aumentar") a menos que se use un artículo indeterminado ("un"). Por lo tanto, sería incorrecto decir:

- Las tasas de interés subieron en 0,5% ayer. (**Incorrecto**)

Deberíamos decir:

- Las tasas de interés subieron **un 0,5%** ayer.
- Las tasas de interés subieron **el 0,5%** ayer.
- Las tasas de interés subieron **en un 0,5%** ayer. (Menos usual)

Lo más común, por lo menos en mi medio, es:

- Las tasas de interés subieron **0,5%** ayer.

Comment: @user13229973 I teach financial translation and this is in fact what I see and use.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Las dos versiones pueden encontrarse después de porcentajes, precios, ventas y exportaciones (cosas que se expresan con números).  Hay una pequeña diferencia entre *subir* y *subir en*:

*Los precios subieron 13%* = Prices rose 13%.
*Los precios subieron en 13%* = Prices rose by 13%.

Comment: Your two English versions are, as far as I can see, identical in meaning so this does not help to answer the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Subir**

1. intr. Ir o moverse hacia arriba .  Los brazos suben lentamente.
2. intr. **Ir desde un lugar a otro más alto** . Sube **AL** piso de arriba. U. t. c. prnl. Se subió AL tejado.
3. intr. Viajar hacia el norte o hacia el origen de algo. Subíamos **POR** el río.
4. intr. Ponerse encima de un animal o de una cosa. Sube **AL** caballo. U. t. c. prnl. Subirse A la escalera.
5. intr. Entrar en un vehículo. Sube AL tren. U. t. c. prnl. Subirse **AL** coche.

...

12. tr. Extenderse por un lugar hacia un punto más alto. Esta calle sube todo el pueblo.
13. tr. Llevar algo o a alguien desde un lugar a otro más alto. Sube los trastos AL desván.
14. tr. Poner a alguien o algo encima de un animal o de una cosa. Sube **al** niño A la silla.
15. tr. Recoger hacia arriba algo que está extendido hacia abajo. Subir el telón, la persiana, el cierre. U. t. c. prnl. Subirse las mangas.
16. tr. Hacer que algo quede más alto. Hay que subir un poco este escalón.
17. tr. Hacer que algo aumente o alcance un nivel más alto. Subir el volumen de la música. El banco sube los intereses.
18. tr. Poner más alto el precio de algo. Ha subido sus productos.
19. tr. Hacer que aumente la intensidad del sonido de un aparato reproductor. Sube el televisor.
20. tr. Poner derecho algo o dirigirlo hacia arriba. Sube la pierna, por favor.

...

https://dle.rae.es/subir

---

De manera general el verbo "**subir**", tiene un valor en sí mismo y dependerá de su contexto para entender el significado, es decir, globalmente no existe un "subir" o un "subir en" de manera especial, pues el verbo "subir" puede ser utilizado con la mayoría de las 23 preposiciones, aunque algunas como cabe y so, ya están en desuso.

Las preposiciones son: **a**, **ante**, **bajo**, cabe, con, contra, de, desde, durante, **en**, entre, hacia, hasta, mediante, para, por, según, sin, so, sobre, tras, versus y vía.

Así podríamos indicar con cada preposición cosas distintas;

- Pedro después de lo sucedido, seguro que se negara a subir **a** un ascensor.
- Subí **ante** la presión de la gente.
- Subimos **bajo** amenazas de muerte.
- Subir **en** paralelo.
- ...

**Oraciones de ejemplos** utilizando como base el que propones en tu pregunta y valiéndonos del lenguaje financiero utilizado en España, **las formas más corrientes serían las siguientes**;

- Las tasas de interés subieron cincuenta puntos básicos ayer y se sitúan **en** el 3% interanual. (*Se sobrentiende que antes el interés estaba en el 2'5 % y con la subida de un 0'5%, se sitúa en el 3%*).
- La tasa de interés subió cincuenta puntos básicos ayer y se sitúa (o situándose), en el 3% interanual.
- La tasa de interés está **en** el 3% interanual.
- La tasa de interés está **al** 3% interanual.
- La tasa de inflación se situó **en el** 10%.
- La inflación subió **al** 10%.
- La inflación subió **hasta** el 10%.
- Los precios subieron **un** 10%.
- Los precios subieron **al** 10%.
- La inflación subió **hasta** el 10%.
- Los precios alcanzaron **el** 10% de inflación.

---

**Notas Especificas Subir/Subir en**

- **Subir(se) a/en** https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-tips/1763-subir-a-subir-en
- **Subir a / Subir en** https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/subir_a/subir_en
- Diccionario panhispánico de dudas **subir(se)**,"a) *Cuando significa ‘ir o llegar a un lugar más alto’ suele llevar un complemento precedido de **a**, **hacia** o **hasta**, que expresa el lugar de destino*:". https://www.rae.es/dpd/subir

**Notas Generales**

- Verbo "Subir", https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/subir
- En una consulta en twitter , "RAE on Twitter":
  Si usa «subir», lo adecuado es que el complemento vaya introducido por la preposición «a»: «Subir a Youtube». Con «colgar», la preposición es «**en**»: «Colgar en Youtube».